# Using period "." in Standard SQL in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery Standard SQL does not seems to allow period "." in the select statement.  Even a simple query (see below) seems to fail.  This is a big problem for datasets with field names that contain "."  Is there an easy way to avoid this issue?

`` select id, time_ts as time.ts
from `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments` 
LIMIT 10 ``

Returns error...
`Error: Syntax error: Unexpected "." at [1:27]`

This also fails...

`select * except(detected_circle.center_x )
from [bigquery-public-data:eclipse_megamovie.photos_v_0_2] 
LIMIT 10`

Comment: What happens if you quote the field as you have done the table name?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. One interpretation is that you want to return a `STRUCT` named `time` with a single field named `ts` inside of it. If that's the case, you can use the `STRUCT` operator to build the result:

```
SELECT
  id,
  STRUCT(time_ts AS ts) AS time
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments` 
LIMIT 10;
```

In the BigQuery UI, it will display the result as `id` and `time.ts`, where the latter indicates that `ts` is inside a `STRUCT` named `time`.

BigQuery disallows columns in the result whose names include periods, so you'll get an error if you run the following query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  time_ts AS `time.ts`
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments` 
LIMIT 10;
```

> Invalid field name "time.ts". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Answer (score 3):

Elliot's answer great and addresses first part of your question, so let me address second part of it (as it is quite different)

First, wanted to mention that select modifiers like `SELECT * EXCEPT` are supported for BigQuery Standard SQL so, instead of

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(detected_circle.center_x )
FROM [bigquery-public-data:eclipse_megamovie.photos_v_0_2] 
LIMIT 10
```

you should rather tried

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(detected_circle.center_x )
FROM `bigquery-public-data.eclipse_megamovie.photos_v_0_2` 
LIMIT 10
```

and of course now we are back to issue with `using period in standard sql

So, above code can only be interpreted as you try to eliminate `center_x` field from `detected_circle` STRUCT (nullable record). Technically speaking, this makes sense and can be done using below code

```sql
SELECT * 
  REPLACE(STRUCT(detected_circle.radius, detected_circle.center_y ) AS detected_circle)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.eclipse_megamovie.photos_v_0_2` 
LIMIT 10
```

> ... still not clear to me how to use your recommendation to remove the entire detected_circle.*

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(detected_circle)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.eclipse_megamovie.photos_v_0_2` 
LIMIT 10
```